# How do I encode numbers (0 to 10000) to a unique word of 5 letters?

Tags: vba, character-encoding, uniqueidentifier

I would need to know how to encode a number in a word of 5 letters;

**It should not be known the sequence from the encoded letters;**

I use VBA for excel.

For example

- 1 => AOPASE
- 2 => AOWPQL
- 839 => SAPQQ

thanks

Comment: what exactly do you mean 'it should not be known the sequence from the encoded letters'?

Comment: If the word is *guaranteed*unique, it's probably going to be possible to reverse it.

Comment: yes, it could be reversable but should not be easily identified how (just by looking at it)

Answer (score 3):

you can implement a hash function for this purpose:

http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/hash_func.html